# How to check the Lebesgue integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have an elementary problem about Lebesgue integrability. How to check the Lebesgue integrability?

I tried to check it by definition, but this definition, you know, is very constructable. So I cannot use it.

Here is my example:

For fixed $n\ge 2$, is $f_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}$ Lebesgue-integrable over $(1,\infty)$?

I cannot start to prove this problem. I'm waiting your hint or solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq 2, x> 1$, $f_n(x) \leq (\frac{x}{n})^{-n} =  \frac{n^n}{x^n}$ which is integrable on $(1,\infty)$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm confused at a moment. :)

Answer (score 3):

For all $n\geqslant2$ and $x\in(1,\infty)$ we have $0\leqslant1+\frac xn\leqslant e^{\frac xn}$ and hence $$0\leqslant\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n} \leqslant \left(e^{\frac xn}\right)^{-n}=e^{-x}. $$
It follows that $$\int_1^\infty \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\,\mathsf dx \leqslant\int_1^\infty e^{-x}\,\mathsf dx = e^{-1}<\infty,  $$ so the function $x\mapsto \left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}$ is integrable on $(1,\infty)$.

Note that this also allows us to use the dominated convergence theorem to compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\,\mathsf dx = \int_1^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{-n}\,\mathsf dx=\int_1^\infty e^{-x}\,\mathsf dx = e^{-1}.  $$

Comment: Oh! I'm solving this problem!:) Thanks.

Comment: $(1+x/n)^n \le e^x \implies (1+x/n)^{-n} \ge e^{-x}.$

Comment: @zhw. Indeed, I will need to revise my argument..